# ZAPIER- Output Missing or Return Early Error in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap, zapier

I'm getting a green alert but my POST is not working and I'm getting the error: output_missing
Please define output or return early.

I am trying to send a SOAP Request with Python:

---

```
url = "https://service.velocify.com/ClientService.asmx"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Host': 'service.velocify.com',
    'Content-Length': '0',
    'SOAPAction': 'https://service.leads360.com/ModifyLeadField'
}

body = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ModifyLeadField xmlns="https://service.leads360.com">
<username>*************</username>
<password>***********</password>
<leadId>310595</leadId>
<fieldId>1238</fieldId>
<newValue>blah</newValue>
</ModifyLeadField>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

"""

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=body)
print(r.content)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Zapier requires you to use the **output** statement in the code, which can then be used in the next Zaps. You can just add something like this at the very end of your code:

```
output = {'response':r.content}
```

and then the key + value will be available in the next Zap.

Comment: Thank you, I added this and then got another error I knew might come up which is "is not JSON serializable". I've tried sending this SOAP request through javascript as well but both seem impossible because a lot of the code I find requires libraries or modules that Zap does not accept. Do you know the best way I can successfully send this SOAP request?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I rechecked the documents about the **output** statement, and it stated that **output** must be JSON serializable. 
https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/use-python-code-in-zaps#data-variables

This may be the error that you are currently experiencing.
In that case, could you check if this works instead:

 ```output = {'response':r.text}```